# Help me understand the proof for Shannon's Theorem 4 (regarding number of sequences of various probabilities) in the original paper

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I'm reading [Shannon's 1948 paper](http://worrydream.com/refs/Shannon%20-%20A%20Mathematical%20Theory%20of%20Communication.pdf) where I encountered [Theorem 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EevO.jpg):

$$
\lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \frac {\log n(q)} N = H
$$

In Appendix 3 after proving Theorem 3, Shannon [proves Theorem 4 by saying:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO2I6.jpg)

> Theorem 4 follows immediately from this on calculating upper and lower
>   bounds for n(q) based on the possible range of values of p in Theorem
>   3.

I don't understand how one calculates upper and lower bounds for n(q). How can p's possible range of values be used for this?

Comment: Note that one can derive upper and lower bounds on on the number of sequences of in the second set from theorem 3 (Denoted $\mathcal{T}$) using the facts that $P(\mathcal{T}) \le 1$ and $P(\mathcal{T}) \ge 1-\epsilon$. Since $q$ is bounded away from $1$, for  $N \ge N_0(1-q)$ and appropritate delta, you only need to look at sequences in $\mathcal{T}$ to get up to $q$. Now bounds on $n(q)$ are forthcoming - you need at most $|\mathcal{T}|$ sequences (for which you know an upper bound), (contd.)

Comment: (contd.)  and since the probabilities of sequences in $\mathcal{T}$ are upper bounded, you similarly have a lower bound on $n(q)$. Playing with how $\delta$ changes with $N$ will give you the limit.

Comment: I should state that the modern formulation of these results renders these theorems much easier to understand and intuitively process. To read these, I suggest going through the sections on typicality in any common Information Theory text (Cover & Thomas is the standard introductory text that does a good job at this).

Comment: @stochasticboy321: If I understand you correctly, you seem to be suggesting this relationship (I don't know how to write the lower bound): $\lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \frac {\log n(q)} N <= \lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \frac {\log |\tau|} N$.  I struggle to see though how this gets me to proving that the limit is $H$

Comment: Oh, so, if you work out the bounyery sufficiently small $\delta >0, \lim \log |\mathcal{T}|/N \le H + \delta \implies \log |\mathcal{T}|/N \le H$. Something similar would hold for the lower bound on $n(q)$, and squeeze theorem will give you the result.

Comment: I still have trouble deriving this with bounds, but here is another idea:  I assume that using theorem 3's $p$ the following holds: $\frac 1 p \approx |\mathcal{T}|$ Is this a valid assumption? If it is, then the following should hold: $H=\lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \frac {\log \frac 1 p} N \approx \lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \frac {\log |\mathcal{T}|} N = \lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \frac {\log |\mathcal{T}|} N + \lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \frac {\log q} N = \lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \frac {\log |\mathcal{T}|q} N \approx \lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \frac {\log n(q)} N$ Is this reasonable?

Comment: Aye, this is fine as a rough idea. You'd have to scratch through the bounds to get to a rigorous proof, though. (Also, apologies for the typos in the previous comment. Hopefully the message wasn't totally obscured.)